# Contain pseudo-class styles within initial ruleset

Tags: html, css, sass

I am styling the `.button1` class with its own ruleset. Additionally, I have a separate ruleset for the `:hover` pseudo-class using the CSS selector `.button1:hover`

But I wish to define the `:hover` pseudo-class styling within the  existing `.button1` ruleset.

#### Currently:

```
.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

#### Desired:

```
.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
    hover:background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

Is it possible to do anything like this?

Here is link https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_hover

Comment: Your saying you want to put the hover inside the element's tag, as an attribute?

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve as of now you are doing right css to get hovering effect

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Sorry but we are not able to understand what is the requirement

Comment: @SaurabhKumarSingh See my answer below

Comment: I dont really understand what your getting at. but you cant put a hover tag inside of a class. Hover is like implements or extends in java, you have to add it on the end of a class or id, you cant put it inside an class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CSS

This is **impossible** to do with pure CSS. :(

`.button1` and `.button1:hover` are different CSS selectors.

With CSS, if you want to apply unique styling to the hover-state, then it must have a separate ruleset:

```
.button1 { background: red; }
.button1:hover { background: pink; }
```

---

### CSS preprocessors

However, there are a handful of **CSS preprocessors** that allow us to write style-rules using special syntaxes that allow nesting similar to what you wish to accomplish.

For instance, here is "SCSS" syntax that the Sass preprocessor uses:

```
.button1 {
    background: red;

    &:hover {
        background: pink;
    }
}
```

On their own, these intermediate syntaxes will not run in the browser, so in the end, a special interpreter (preprocessor) must be used to "process" and translate the special syntax into real CSS that the browser can actually load.

#### Some popular preprocessors:

- [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/)
- [Less](http://lesscss.org/)
- [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)
- [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/)

Comment: thanks mirr,we are using scss , I should have mentioned that in my question

Comment: @SaurabhKumarSingh No problem! Note the special `&` character. It's a special placeholder that is used in nested rules to represent the css-selector from the parent. So `&:hover` is equivalent to `.button1:hover` because the parent-selector in that case is `.button1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get hovering effect -

```
<style>
    .btn{
        /* Style your button */
    }
    .btn:hover{
        /* Add hovering effect to your button */
    }
</style>
<button class="btn">Green</button>
```

Comment: I think hes asking if he can put :hover inside a class? ... for some reason

Comment: @ScottChambers yes scott

Comment: @SaurabhKumarSingh but why?

Comment: Try using `transition`

Comment: Or as per his comment if you are using similar buttosn like confirm button then you can define a class `.btn-cnf` and add the hovering and styling in same class like `.btn-cnf:hover` not like `.button1, .button2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add hover to any class the format is 
You can not add it inside .button class

```
.button1:hover{
   background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```